# Prolog - Appending to list recursively

Tags: prolog

I wrote this function where I have as a parameter a set of coordinates and I want to create a new list with all the coordinates to the left of them (so basically X-1) but at the end it doesn't ask me if the option given is correct, it just prints `yes`.
Here is the code:

```
all_valid_moves([], L):-
    write('------------------------'),
    nl,
    write(L),
    nl,
    write('------------------------'),
    nl,
    !.
all_valid_moves([Head|Tail], All_Valid):-
    nth0(0, Head, X),
    nth0(1, Head, Y),
    NewX is X - 1,
    append([[NewX, Y]], All_Valid, New_All_Valid),
    write(All_Valid),
    nl,
    all_valid_moves(Tail, New_All_Valid).
```

Test case `all_valid_moves([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], X).`.
Should return `[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]`.

If anyone can point out the mistake(s) I made, please do so!
Thanks alot for your time,
Have a good one

Comment: Hint: could use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3

Comment: Would usually have a `valid_move` predicate, then run a `bagof` on that, to create the list of all valid moves.

Answer (score 1):

**Final answer**

I added a new variable to the function so I could return it in a new list, this was the final result:

```
all_valid_moves(Board, [], L, New):-
    New = L.
all_valid_moves(Board, [Head|Tail], Previous, All_Valid):-
    nth0(0, Head, X),
    nth0(1, Head, Y),
    NewX is X - 1,
    append([[NewX, Y]], All_Valid, New_All_Valid),
    all_valid_moves(Board, Tail, New_Prev3, New_All_Valid),
    All_Valid = New_All_Valid.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify, simplify, simplify. No need for `nth0/3`. No need for `append/3`. Just this:

```
all_valid_moves( []         , []          ) .
all_valid_moves( [[X,Y]|As] , [[X1,Y]|Bs] ) :- X1 is X-1, all_valid_moves(As,Bs).
```